# Query performance issue - Not in

Tags: peoplesoft

The query below is created by someone else but is running long so need to improve the performance. Can you please suggest me a better way to do?

```
Select * from ps_vendor G where G.vendor_id NOT IN (SELECT vendor_id 
                               FROM   ps_voucher_line 
                               WHERE  vendor_id <> '70830' 
                                      AND cntrct_id <> ' ' 
                                      AND vendor_id NOT IN (SELECT vendor_id 
                                                            FROM   ps_cntrct_hdr 
                                                            WHERE 
                                          cntrct_type = 'AP'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with inner join condition like display below

```
Select G.* from ps_vendor G 
       inner join ps_voucher_line  pvl
            on G.vendor_id = pvl.vendor_id and pvl.vendor_id  <> '70830'
        inner join ps_cntrct_hdr pch
            on  (pch.vendor_id <> pvl.vendor_id and pch.cntrct_type = 'AP')
    where pv.cntrct_id <> ' '
```

Try different variations in joining condition!!

Good is that you have sub query to verify results.

Comment: I modified it by adding a left outer join that improved the performance but returning extra rows that needs to be corrected.                                                              Select * from ps_vendor G where G.vendor_id NOT IN ( 
 SELECT s.vendor_id 
  FROM ps_voucher_line s LEFT OUTER JOIN ps_cntrct_hdr t ON s.cntrct_id=t.cntrct_id 
 WHERE s.vendor_id <> '70830' 
   AND s.cntrct_id <> ' ' 
   AND t.cntrct_type = 'AP' 
   AND t.cntrct_id IS NULL)

Comment: extra records in left join conditions can be easily remove by putting null check in join condition, as well .

Comment: I have used a null condition but that is still giving extra rows.Please tell me if anything is wrong there

Comment: can you use sqlfiddle ? to explain issue by dumping test data i.e. check this 

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/796b2f/43 that will be helpful for me to try for best

Comment: tell me from which table extra records are coming those are normally due to left join, It did bring null entries of the other table